# fastload shows up as active but I dont see any entry in fastlog

Tags: sql, database, teradata, etl, data-warehouse

I am on Teradata 15 where fastload 19 sessions are seen as active but
there is NO entry at all in fastlog 
In fact there are **far too less entries**  in that table for such a huge system as this ..I am probably missing something here .
Does TPT Load runnning in fastload partition do something different in terms of logging checkpoints. 
My understanding was that even if the fastload took place earlier there should be these values that kind of give some 'history'

```
StartDate
StartTime
EndDate
Endtime
```

So if I don't see any entry for this  *Db.tb* being loaded can I assume its gone zombie and needs to be dropped / dummied ( dummy start / end )

So how does this fastlog work ? Every  present / past fastload attempt that has been active should be there  or does it get deleted based on some condition

AFAIK there is just 1 location for logtable and that is the location of fastlog - but have things changed and there is some other definable location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only standalone FastLoad uses the `sysadmin.fastlog` table, when a job finishes it deletes the row. If there are rows and no job is currently running some previous (might be years ago) FastLoads did not finish correctly. Usually you can delete them manually, the target table of such a job might not even exist anymore.

TPT `LOAD` uses the FastLod protocol, but each TPT job has its own logtable. If the `LogTable` attribute is not specified in the TPT script it defaults to `target_table_RL`, you might check `dbc.TablesV where TableName like '%\_RL' escape '\'`.